# Implementing Division of Streams (where it's a stream of polynomial coefficients)

Tags: haskell

Per this [homework](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/06-laziness.pdf), I'm trying to implement a `Fractional (Stream Integer)` where the stream represents coefficients of polynomials:

> where Q is defined as Q = (A'/b0) + x((1/b0)(A' − QB0)).
>
> where A/B = Q,
>
> That is, the first element of the result is A'/b0; the remainder is
>   formed by computing A' − QB' and dividing each of its elements by b0
>
> Note that A' == tail of A and same for B'

Here's my attempt:

```
divStreams :: Stream Integer -> Stream Integer -> Stream Integer
divStreams a@(Cons x xs) b@(Cons y ys) = 
    Cons (x `div` y) (streamMap ((1 `div` y) *) xs - (multStreams q ys) ) 
      where q = divStreams a b
```

with the following functions' definitions:

```
multStreams :: Stream Integer -> Stream Integer -> Stream Integer
multStreams (Cons x xs) b@(Cons y ys) = 
    Cons (x * y) (streamMap (*x) ys + multStreams xs b)

data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)

streamMap :: (a -> b) -> Stream a -> Stream b
streamMap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) rest
   where rest = streamMap f xs
```

Note that I defined `Num (Stream Integer)` where `(+)` == `combineStreams (+)`

```
combineStreams :: (a -> b -> c) -> Stream a -> Stream b -> Stream c
combineStreams f (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = Cons (f x y) rest
   where rest = combineStreams f xs ys
```

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26579938) that resolved an issue I had implementing multiplication of Streams.

Comment: You have not implemented division of streams here though, you implemented multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of cases where using `where` isn't gaining us anything. For instance, `combineStreams` can just be written as

```
combineStreams :: (a -> b -> c) -> Stream a -> Stream b -> Stream c
combineStreams f (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = Cons (f x y) (combineStreams f xs ys)
```

Same goes for `streamMap`.

If you're not using `combineStreams` anywhere else, we can just write

```
instance Num (Stream Integer) where
    (Cons x xs) + (Cons y ys) = Cons (x + y) (xs + ys)
```

---

I just want to repeat the definition given in the homework, for clarity:

> If \$A = a_0 + x A'\$ and \$B = b_0 + x B'\$, then \$A / B = Q\$,
>   where \$Q\$ is defined as
>
> \begin{align} Q = (a_0 / b_0) + x((1 / b_0)(A' - QB')). \end{align}

Your definition of `divStreams` is very close to this, but we can use the following trick where `q` refers to itself, just as in the formula above:

```
divStreams :: Stream Integer -> Stream Integer -> Stream Integer
divStreams (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = 
    let q = Cons (x `div` y) (streamMap ((1 `div` y) *) (xs - q * ys)) in q
```

assuming you have defined `*` to be `multStreams`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my extra, wasteful `where`'s, as well as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

### Duplicate Call to `divStreams`

This duplication is already mentioned by @mjolka, but I want to add that this kind of duplication may lead to unnecessary function calls. You can fix it using `let`, but using `where` also works. Definite way to test this kind of problem (that I know of) is using [Debug.Trace.trace](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Debug-Trace.html). (In this case problem seems to be optimized away by the compiler, but you should not leave important behavior compiler implementation and version dependent)

```
import Debug.Trace

divStreams a@(Cons x xs) b@(Cons y ys) =
    "divStreams called" `trace` Cons (x `div` y) (streamMap ((1 `div` y) *) xs - (multStreams q ys)) 
      where q = divStreams a b
```

versus

```
divStreams a@(Cons x xs) b@(Cons y ys) =
    "divStreams called" `trace` q
      where q = Cons (x `div` y) (streamMap ((1 `div` y) *) xs - (multStreams q ys))
```

### Misuse of `div`

`streamMap ((1`div`y) *)` only works for `y=1` or `y=-1`. For other y the tail of the stream will all be zeros, even when it should not be.

Fixing it is easy: just replace `streamMap ((1`div`y) *)` with `streamMap (`div`y)`.

Before we test, some definitions:

```
take' :: Int -> (Stream a) -> [a]
take' n _      | n <= 0 = []
take' n (Cons x xs)     = x : take' (n-1) xs

instance (Show a) => Show (Stream a) where
  show xs = show (take' 10 xs)

instance (Num a) => Num (Stream a) where
  (+) = combineStreams (+)
  negate = streamMap ((-1)*)
```

A simple test case is this:

```
divStreams' a@(Cons x xs) b@(Cons y ys) = q
      where q = Cons (x `div` y) (streamMap (`div` y) xs - (multStreams q ys))
ones = Cons 1 ones
twos = Cons 2 twos
onesTimesTwos = multStreams ones twos
ones' = divStreams onesTimesTwos twos
ones'' = divStreams' onesTimesTwos twos

> streamMap ((1 `div` 2) *) twos
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
> streamMap (`div` 2) twos
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
>ones'
[1,-2,2,-2,2,-2,2,-2,2,-2]-- expected 1, 1, 1, 1, ....

>ones''
[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0] -- expected 1, 1, 1, 1, ....
```

oops. A bug still remains.